# Why does $\int_{0}^{\infty} \lambda e^{(t-\lambda)x} dx$ exist?

Tags: calculus, integration

According to my textbook (Grinstead and Snell's Introduction to Probability), $\int_{0}^{\infty} \lambda e^{(t-\lambda)x} dx = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda-t}$.

But it seems to me like there are two solutions. If $t \gt \lambda$, then $\int_{}^{}\ldots = \frac{\lambda}{t - \lambda}$, and if $t < \lambda$, then $\int_{}^{}\ldots = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda - t}$. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $t\ge\lambda$, the integral diverges. It is implicit that $t<\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lambda\int_0^{+\infty} e^{ax} \text{d}x$$

where $a = t-\lambda$

Solving that ad you will get

$$\lambda\left(\frac{e^{ax}}{a}\bigg|_{0}^{+\infty}\right)$$

$a$ has to be negative, otherwise the integral diverges. So you have to have $t-\lambda < 0$